# How to use org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection class of HSQLDB API

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, hsqldb

I understand it is useful to use `org.hsqldb.server.Server` class when creating a hsqldb server programmatically.

I always used java SDK class (`java.sql.Connection`) to connect to the server and I feel it is enough to connect whether the server is memory-based or file-based.

Why do we need `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection` class of hsqldb API?

Comment: Thanks to AmitK for editing the Question!!

Comment: Thanks Mrak for editing my question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'class' `java.sql.Connection`: it is an interface. JDBC is an API that consists of interfaces (and some supporting classes). Those interfaces need to be implemented by each and every JDBC driver to actually be able to do anything.

When you use HSQLDB, you use its implementation of `java.sql.Connection` called `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection`; this contains the specifics of how HSQLDB works (something which JDBC itself doesn't know). However usually you only need to access it through the interface defined in JDBC; that is even preferable for portability.

So in short, if it wasn't for `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection`, you would not even be able to connect to a HSQLDB.

Comment: **Implementation versus interface...**  Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with HSQLDB much but API documentation seems best source for your question.

Documentation of [Class JDBCConnection](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCConnection.html) says -

> JDBC 4.0 Notes:
>
> Starting with JDBC 4.0 (JDK 1.6), the DriverManager methods
>   getConnection and getDrivers have been enhanced to support the Java
>   Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. When built under a Java
>   runtime that supports JDBC 4.0, HSQLDB distribution jars containing
>   the Driver implementation also include the file
>   META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the fully
>   qualified class name ('org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver') of the HSQLDB
>   implementation of java.sql.Driver.
>
> Hence, under JDBC 4.0 or greater, applications no longer need to
>   explicitly load the HSQLDB JDBC driver using Class.forName(). Of
>   course, existing programs which do load JDBC drivers using
>   Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.

So I guess you can continue with standardized code.

This class might have some additional methods specific to HSQLDB.

Also, you will have to type-cast if planning to use those specific methods,

```
JDBCConnection connection =
            (JDBCConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, connProperties);
```

Regarding your other question, pattern is - `<url>[;key=value]*` i.e. you place a semicolon after url then specify key - values in `key=value` format. Each `key=value` needs to be separated by semicolon.

e.g. `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/cities;user=bill;password=password` 
i.e. you add a semicolon before appending a key value pair and no semicolon for last key value pair.

Comment: Thanks Sabir,.  It helps a lot.  One additional question if you do not mind.  On the same page of the API, there is **HSQLDB-Specific Information** at the end.   It says: Since 1.7.2, connection properties (<key-value-pairs>) may be appended to the database connection <url>, using the form:'<url>[;key=value]*'   Could you explain a little bit or show a simple example?   I have hard time to understand this.

Comment: @Bll You should really have asked that as a new question.

Comment: Thanks Mark,  I will create a new Question for this API part.